# Turbofish does not infer type correctly

Tags: mysql, rust

I'm using the `mysql` crate, specifically the `query_first` [method](https://docs.rs/mysql/18.1.0/mysql/prelude/trait.Queryable.html#method.query_first). Running the following snippet compiled perfectly.

```rust
let foo : mysql::Result<Option<u64>> = tx.query_first("SELECT row_count();");
```

For ergonomic purposes, I want to embed that call at the top-level of a `match`, so that I can test multiple cases. To infer the missing type, I use the turbofish operator (see following snippet). However, that does not compile.

```rust
match tx.query_first::<mysql::Result<Option<u64>>>("SELECT row_count();") {
  Ok(Some(num)) => {}
  Ok(None) => {}
  Err(e) => {}
};
```

Am I not using turbofish correctly?

The compiler errors are:

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 2, found 1
   --> src/main.rs:224:22
    |
224 |             match tx.query_first::<mysql::Result<Option<u64>>>("SELECT row_count();") {
    |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected 2 type arguments

error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::result::Result<std::option::Option<u64>, mysql::error::Error>: mysql_common::value::convert::FromValue` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:224:22
    |
224 |             match tx.query_first::<mysql::Result<Option<u64>>>("SELECT row_count();") {
    |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `mysql_common::value::convert::FromValue` is not implemented for `std::result::Result<std::option::Option<u64>, mysql::er
ror::Error>`
    |
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `mysql_common::row::convert::FromRow` for `std::result::Result<std::option::Option<u64>, mysql::error::Err
or>`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the function `query_first` takes two generic parameters, you still have to provide two in the turbofish notation.

The other issue is that you are passing to turbofish the wrong type: `query_first` returns a `Result<Option<T>>`, so if you want to get a `Result<Option<u64>>`, T must be `u64`.

Combine this together with an ignored binding `_` to the second type which lets the compiler infer it, so this should work (as the generic type Q is the second parameter):

```
query_first::<u64, _>
```

Comment: Thanks, it didn't click in my head that turbofish must fill in the generic parameters of a method, rather than fill in the return type. Makes sense now!